# Debugging Mult-Project ASP.Net Solution is Visual Studio Code

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to debug an ASP.Net Core web application with multiple projects in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out! In my solution folders I have the following projects:

- -Project.Data
- -Project.Domain
- -Project.WebApi

When you are in the solution folder and try to run the debugger, VS Code will add a .vscode folder and place a launch.json file in it. All you have to do is modify the "program" property under the "configurations" section. It originally looks like:

```
"${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>"
```

Change it to:

```
"${workspaceRoot}/<project-name>/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>"
```

So mine now looks like:

```
"${workspaceRoot}/Project.WebApi/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/Project.WebApi.dll"
```

If the application creates a tasks.json, you will need to add a new item in the "args" array for the build task like:

```
"${workspaceRoot}/<project-name>/project.json"
```

So mine now looks like:

```
"${workspaceRoot}/Project.WebApi/project.json"
```

Make sure you add an item in this array for each of the projects in your solution.

My solution file structure now looks like:

- -.vscode
- -Project.Data
- -Project.Domain
- -Project.WebApi

Now, when I run the debugger, it looks in the appropriate "start up project" to run the application.